# Single email from multiple Hudson project builds

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I currently have several Hudson projects linked together.

The main project checks out from svn and builds a .net solution using msbuild.  This project has a list of post build projects to run which uses the the msdeploy command line to deploy to various servers etc.

At the moment I have an email sent out using the Editable Email Notification package from the first project stating the changes in subversion and the build status and no emails from the subsequent msdeploy projects.

What I want to do is turn on email notifications from all the projects but rather than having multiple emails have one email combining all the output from all the linked projects.

Does anyone know a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that such an option is available currently in Hudson.  One possible option, though, might be to enable emails only for failure-type builds (failing, still-failing, etc), and use some other notification mechanism (IRC, Growl, Twitter, whatever suits your needs) for successful builds.  That assumes, of course, that "successful" builds are your projects' normal status.